# question about select2, The old row becomes regular HTML and no longer becomes select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to create a new row when clicking a button and that row should have 2 select2, for some reason when initializing select2, the new row becomes select2 but the old row becomes regular HTML. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="advanceModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document" style="max-width: 650px">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6 class="modal-title">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_check_if_activated') }}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <select class="form-control advance_label" id="advance_label" name="advance_label" style="width: 100%">
                                <option></option>
                                <option value="GroupCompany">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_group_company') }}</option>
                                <option value="Department">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_department') }}</option>
                                <option value="Location">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_location') }}</option>
                                <option value="WorkingUnit">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_working_unit') }}</option>
                                <option value="EmployeeType">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_employee_type') }}</option>
                                <option value="KelasCabang">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_kelas_cabang') }}</option>
                                <option value="Segmen">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_segmen') }}</option>
                                <option value="Position">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_position') }}</option>
                                <option value="KlasifikasiJabatan">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.label_klasifikasi_jabatan') }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="mr-auto float-left">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="btn_add_filter" style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.btn_add') }}</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal" style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px;">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_apply" style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px;">{{ __('tm_absenteeism_data_entry_by_employee_no.btn_apply') }}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

$('#btn_add_filter').click(function() {
            var newRow = '<div class="row">' +
                            '<div class="col-5">' +
                                '<select class="form-control advance_label" id="advance_label" name="advance_label" style="width: 100%">' +
                                    '<option></option>' +
                                    '<option value="GroupCompany">Group Company</option>' +
                                    '<option value="Department">Department</option>' +
                                    '<option value="Location">Location</option>' +
                                    '<option value="WorkingUnit">Working Unit</option>' +
                                    '<option value="EmployeeType">Employee Type</option>' +
                                    '<option value="KelasCabang">Kelas Cabang</option>' +
                                    '<option value="Segmen">Segmen</option>' +
                                    '<option value="Position">Position</option>' +
                                    '<option value="KlasifikasiJabatan">Klasifikasi Jabatan</option>' +
                                '</select>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="col-1">' +
                                '<div class="box-delete">' +
                                    '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
            
            $('.modal-body .row:last').after(newRow);

            $('.modal-body .row:last .advance_label').select2({
                placeholder: "Select Filter"
            });

            $('.modal-body .row:last .advance_filter').select2({
                placeholder: "Select Filter"
            });
        });
```

as you can see, i want to create a new row when i clicked a button, but the old row becomes regular HTML. can someone please tell me why and how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but ids and names are supposed to be unique. Each time you press the button, another select with `id="advance_label" name="advance_label"` is added.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue (ideally without server-side tags).  See [mcve]. "the old row *becomes*" is not demonstrated. See https://jsfiddle.net/tp5o0uhs/  **Your code does not *initialise* the first row**, so it's never a select2 - there's nothing here that makes it a select2 and the restores it back to HTML.  Otherwise, your code works fine (albeit with some irrelevant redundancies)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, by the time your `select2` initialisation is executed, the `newRow` is not appended to the DOM yet. Even though you have sequentially added the statements, it takes few milli/nanoseconds to alter the DOM, by the time which the next statement would have executed. Try to initialise the select2 before attaching to DOM like,

```js
const select2Element = $(newRow).select2({
  placeholder: "Select Filter"
});

$('.modal-body .row:last').after(select2Element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a new class with random integer at last of it and then initialize the select2.

```
$('#btn_add_filter').click(function() {
var randomnumber = new Date().getTime();
        var newRow = '<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="col-5">' +
                            '<select class="form-control advance_label select2'+'" id="advance_label" name="advance_label" style="width: 100%">' +
                                '<option></option>' +
                                '<option value="GroupCompany">Group Company</option>' +
                                '<option value="Department">Department</option>' +
                                '<option value="Location">Location</option>' +
                                '<option value="WorkingUnit">Working Unit</option>' +
                                '<option value="EmployeeType">Employee Type</option>' +
                                '<option value="KelasCabang">Kelas Cabang</option>' +
                                '<option value="Segmen">Segmen</option>' +
                                '<option value="Position">Position</option>' +
                                '<option value="KlasifikasiJabatan">Klasifikasi Jabatan</option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-1">' +
                            '<div class="box-delete">' +
                                '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
        
        $('.modal-body .row:last').after(newRow);

        $('.modal-body .row:last .select2'+randomnumber).select2({
            placeholder: "Select Filter"
        });

        $('.modal-body .row:last .select2'+randomnumber).select2({
            placeholder: "Select Filter"
        });
    });
```

Just replace your js with it.

Comment: No need, if you use `$(newRow).insertAfter("...")` then it returns the newRow jquery object, so you can the just `$(newRow).insertAfter(..).find("select").select2(..`

Answer (score 0):

> **[Select2 does not function properly when I use it inside a Bootstrap modal.](https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems)**

> This issue occurs because Bootstrap modals tend to steal focus from
> other elements outside of the modal. Since by default, Select2
> attaches the dropdown menu to the  element, it is considered
> "outside of the modal".
>
> To avoid this problem, you may attach the dropdown to the modal itself
> with the dropdownParent setting:

Modified relevant code by adding `dropdownParent: '#advanceModal'`.

```
  $('.modal-body .row:last .advance_label').select2({
    placeholder: "Select Filter",
    dropdownParent: '#advanceModal'
  });
```

Below snippet best viewed in full screen

```js
$('.modal-body .row:last select.advance_label').select2({
  placeholder: "Select Filter",
  dropdownParent: '#advanceModal'
});

$('#btn_add_filter').click(function() {
  var newRow = '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-5">' +
    '<select class="form-control advance_label" name="advance_label" style="width: 100%">' +
    '<option></option>' +
    '<option value="GroupCompany">Group Company</option>' +
    '<option value="Department">Department</option>' +
    '<option value="Location">Location</option>' +
    '<option value="WorkingUnit">Working Unit</option>' +
    '<option value="EmployeeType">Employee Type</option>' +
    '<option value="KelasCabang">Kelas Cabang</option>' +
    '<option value="Segmen">Segmen</option>' +
    '<option value="Position">Position</option>' +
    '<option value="KlasifikasiJabatan">Klasifikasi Jabatan</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-1">' +
    '<div class="box-delete">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  $('.modal-body .row:last').after(newRow);

  $('.modal-body .row:last .advance_label').select2({
    placeholder: "Select Filter",
    dropdownParent: '#advanceModal'
  });

  // $('.modal-body .row:last .advance_filter').select2({
  /*  $('select.advance_filter:last').select2({
      placeholder: "Select Filter",
      dropdownParent: '#advanceModal'
    }); */
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Rx+T1VzGupg4BHQYs2gCW9It+akI2MM/mndMCy36UVfodzcJcF0GGLxZIzObiEfa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="advanceModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document" style="max-width: 650px;">
      <div class="modal-content" style="min-height: 400px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h6 class="modal-title">Modal</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
              <select class="form-control advance_label" id="advance_label" name="advance_label" style="width: 100%">
                <option></option>
                <option value="GroupCompany">GroupCompany</option>
                <option value="Department">Department</option>
                <option value="Location">Location</option>
                <option value="WorkingUnit">WorkingUnit</option>
                <option value="EmployeeType">EmployeeType</option>
                <option value="KelasCabang">KelasCabang</option>
                <option value="Segmen">Segmen</option>
                <option value="Position">Position</option>
                <option value="KlasifikasiJabatan">KlasifikasiJabatan</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="mr-auto float-left">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="btn_add_filter" style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Filter</button>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px;">Cancel</button>
              <!-- button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_apply" style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px;">Apply</button -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bd-example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#advanceModal">
    Launch modal
  </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```